# Is NavigationView used in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Is it possible to use Microsoft made NavigationView in Wpf? I use it in UWP projects. It looks very nice and useful. I am talking about the tool whose link is shared below.

[NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview)

Comment: You can use Xaml Islands to embed UWP controls in WPF

Comment: I found an example. But it's made with ".NET Core". Is it possible in the ".NET Framework" project as well?

Comment: Unfortunately no, your only option is to upgrade to .NET Core

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am currently trying to upgrade ".NET Core". I have done compatibility analysis as mentioned  here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) . The whole project is compatible with ".Net Core + Platform Extensions, Version 3.1".

Is there an instruction for this upgrade? Unfortunately I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is NavigationView used in wpf?

I have to say, you can't use the `NavigationView` control in wpf xaml directly. However, you can use Xaml Islands to approach. And here is [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands).

And please note

*Using XAML Islands to host WinRT XAML controls in WPF and Windows Forms apps is currently supported only in apps that target .NET Core 3.x. XAML Islands are not yet supported in apps that target .NET 5, or in apps that any version of the .NET Framework.*

For upgrade to .net core, please refer [Upgrade a WPF App to .NET 5 with the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework) document.